# Stackoverflow Exception on get function for a property

Tags: c#, sql, stack-overflow

I have the following simple class to manage my SQL database operations

```
public class DatabaseManager
    {


        private string CommandString
        {
             set { CommandString = GetCommandString(commandtype); }
             get { return CommandString; }
        }
        public string commandtype
        {
            set;
            get;
        }



        public DatabaseManager(string commandtype)
        {
            commandtype = this.commandtype;
            CommandString = GetCommandString(commandtype);
        }

        public DatabaseManager()
        {

        }       


        public static SqlConnection CreateConnection()
        {
            return new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString);
        }




        //returns a datatable if the command requires a dataadapter
        public DataTable ExecuteSelect()
        {
            var x = new DataTable();
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(CommandString, DatabaseManager.CreateConnection()))
                {
                    da.Fill(x);
                }

            return x;
        }




        private string GetCommandString(string commandtype)
        {


            switch (commandtype)
            {
                // select commands
                case ("SELECTMARGINS"): CommandString = "select * from margins"; break;
                case ("SELECTRANKS"): CommandString = "select * from ranks"; break;
                /...and other commands

            return CommandString;
        }

    }
```

i am getting a Stackoverflow exception on `get { return CommandString; }`

Comment: you are running in infinite loop in get of `CommandString`, because return `CommandString` calls its own getter. Introduce a backing field. `private string _commandString`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `get` function is your problem

```
 get { return CommandString; }
```

This is the morale equivalent of the following

```
public string GetCommandString() { 
  return GetCommandString();
}
```

This will just create infinite recursion and eventually a `StackOverflowException` will be thrown.  You need to change the `get` and `set` to operate on a backing field which holds the actual value and use that instead

```
private string _commandString;
public string CommandString {
  get { return _commandString; }
  set { _commandString = GetCommandString(commandtype); }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't have a property return itself (it creates an infinite loop).

```
    private string _CommandString;
    public string CommandString
    {
         set { _CommandString = GetCommandString(commandtype); }
         get { return _CommandString; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set or even get `CommandString`, you have to create a private variable in this case.

```
private string _commandString;
public string CommandString
{
     set { _commandString = GetCommandString(commandtype); }
     get { return _commandString; }
}
```

What is happening in your current code is that you are doing something like this:

```
CommandString = "x";
```

which calls

```
CommandString = GetCommandString(type);
```

which calls

```
CommandString = GetCommandString(type);
```

etc....so it keeps looping until it overflow. The private variable keeps you from setting the same property over and over again

Also, it looks like you are never actually using the `value` passed into the set function, which seems like a bug

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a Get function return itself, it will just cause it to infinitely attempt to retrieve itself until the stack overflows.

Create a private variable to get and set to:

```
private string _CommandString;
private string CommandString
{
    //Also you probably want to change commandtype to value, since you will be
    //discarding whatever you attempt to set the variable as
    set { _CommandString = GetCommandString(commandtype); } 
    get { return _CommandString; }
}
```